# Drawing a picture using GDI+ in WinAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

There is a simple code to draw an image on the window using GDI+:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

void Example_DrawImage9(HDC hdc) {
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Image image(L"C:/Users/Darek/Fallout2/data/art/iface/armor_info.bmp");
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 10, 10);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    ULONG_PTR token;
    GdiplusStartupInput input = { 0 };
    input.GdiplusVersion = 1;
    GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc; //attach this callback procedure
    wc.hInstance = hInstance; //handle to application instance
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc); //register wc

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"Learn to Program Windows",  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd != NULL)   {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(token);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
            Example_DrawImage9(hdc);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Is there a way to hide, or make transparent, the window hosting the image, so after the app is started it just shows only the picture?

Comment: You mean you want the window borders and title bar to disappear?

Comment: @GSerg. Yes, exactly. I wont to see ONLY the image itself.

Comment: This is using GDI+, not GDI, but the question is unrelated to either.

Comment: @IInspectable. Ok, right this is GDI+, but why do You think my question  is unrelated to either?

Comment: @GSerg Is the `WS_POPUP` style the only option?

Comment: Rendering an image appears to be a solved issue, hence this question isn't about the GDI (or GDI+). It's about the windowing system, part of the USER component.